# Enter Key tricks val() length / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm disabling the submit button until something is entered. The problem is that the Enter Key is counting as a Character or "length".

This is for a **TextArea**

**Count.js.coffee**

```
$(document).ready ->
  $(".cmnt_btn").attr "disabled", true
  $(".cmnt_area").keyup ->
    # Disable button when nothing is entered
    # Enter Key tricks this
    unless $(this).val().length is 0
      $(".cmnt_btn").attr "disabled", false
    else
      $(".cmnt_btn").attr "disabled", true
    # Character Count
    left = 300 - $(this).val().length
    left = 0  if left < 0
    $(".cmnt_counter").text left
```

How can i "disable" the enter Key counting as a Character or disabling the key until something else is entered ?

Comment: It's probably not that the enter key is counted as length, but that hitting enter submits the form ?

Comment: No no, pressing enter breaks the line and it counts as length > 0. It's a TextArea

Comment: Oh ok, if it's for a textarea just use `$.trim( $(this).val() ).length` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably asking to trim new lines / spaces from the beginning and end of a textarea:

```
$(this).val().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').length
```

Also, setting true/false on the disabled attribute will do nothing: replace them with prop.

Comment: Could you refactor my Code (prop) so i can see how it's done correctly ? Thanks.

Comment: You just literally replace every instance of "attr" to "prop".